# TypeError: "x" is (not) "y" after destructuring an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

In my react app, when I run this code I get `TypeError: "x" is (not) "y"`:

```
deletePersonHandler = (personIndex) => {
    const { persons } = this.state.persons;
    persons.splice(personIndex, 1);
    this.setState({ persons });
}
```

There is no problem when I do not use destructuring:

```
deletePersonHandler = (personIndex) => {
    const persons = this.state.persons;
    persons.splice(personIndex, 1);
    this.setState({ persons });
}
```

If it helps this method is passed into a functional component as a click property:

```
        persons = (
            <div>
                {this.state.persons.map((person, index) => {
                    return <Person name={person.person} age={person.age} click={() => this.deletePersonHandler(index)} changed={this.nameChangedHandler.bind(this)} />;
                })}
            </div>
        );
```

Why does destructuring make a difference?

Comment: `const { persons } = this.state;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to destructure `this.state.persons` as an object with a property of `persons` - but you want the `persons` property of `this.state`, not the `persons` property of `this.state.persons` (which doesn't exist). Instead, do:

```
const { persons } = this.state;
```